# Why doc['innerObject.seqId'].value.toBigInteger() does not return the max in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, aggregation

Running the following Elasticsearch 2.2 aggrigation does not return the max value for`seqId` that is of type of `String` in my Elasticsearch index:

```
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "max_seqId" : {
        "max" : { "script" : {
                    "inline": "doc['innerObject.seqId'].value.toBigInteger()", 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that some of your docs might not contain a value for the `'innerObject.seqId'` field - either the field itself is missing or have an explicit `null` value assigned to it.

In both these cases you are evaluating the method `toBigInteger()` on a null object which yields NPE.

You may try it this way using an **exists** query to filter out the missing value docs before evaluating the script:

```
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "exists": {
         "field": "innerObject.seqId"
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "max_seqId": {
         "max": {
            "script": {
               "inline": "doc['innerObject.seqId'].value.toBigInteger()"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```